# Using C++ std::enable_if with a normal function?

Tags: c++, templates

let's say I have an enumeration:

```
typedef enum {
  Val1,
  Val2,
  Val3,
  Val4
} vals;
```

And a function `check(vals x)` which returns a boolean indicating whether the val is in a specific subset of values in `vals`.

```
bool check(vals x) {
  switch(x) {
  case Val1:
  case Val3:
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

I want to use this function as a condition for the `enable_if` (the function, as you can see, it's not a function depending on the runtime), to let the users use only those values with the class template.

```
class MyClass<vals v> {

}
```

PS: I need the template to make specializations for a method of the class, depending on the template value.

Comment: Have you tried making `check` `constexpr`?

Comment: @KABoissonneault I should take a look at C++11 features more frequently. Thanks!

Comment: @osnapitzkindle: I don't think a C++11 compiler will accept the `switch` in a `constexpr` function, but you can re-express using a boolean expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need neither a function nor `enable_if` to do that.
Here is an example:

```
enum class vals {
    Val1,
    Val2,
    Val3,
    Val4
};

template<vals v, bool = (v == vals::Val1 || v == vals::Val3)>
class MyClass;

template<vals v>
class MyClass<v, true> { };

int main() {
    MyClass<vals::Val1> ok;
    // MyClass<vals::Val2> ko;
}
```

This solution has actually a problem: `MyClass<vals::Val2, true> ok;` is a valid statement.
Anyway, if it fits well mostly depends on the real problem.

If you want to use `enable_if` you can do this:

```
#include<type_traits>

enum class vals {
    Val1,
    Val2,
    Val3,
    Val4
};

template<vals v, std::enable_if_t<(v == vals::Val1 || v == vals::Val3)>* = nullptr>
class MyClass { };

int main() {
    MyClass<vals::Val1> ok;
    // MyClass<vals::Val2> ko;
}
```

Another solution would be using a `static_assert`:

```
enum class vals {
    Val1,
    Val2,
    Val3,
    Val4
};

template<vals v>
class MyClass {
    static_assert((v == vals::Val1 || v == vals::Val3), "!");
};

int main() {
    MyClass<vals::Val1> ok;
    // MyClass<vals::Val2> ko;
}
```

And so on, there exist a bunch of alternatives that does not require a `constexpr`ed function.

Otherwise let the function be `constexpr` as mentioned by @n.m. and that's all.

Answer (score 6):

In C++14, just declare the function `constexpr` and keep the implementation as is.

In C+11 you need to change it to a single return statement:

```
constexpr bool check(vals x) {
    return x == Val1 || x == Val3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer guys.
I found another solution that could be even better for my problem.
Since I have to implement a specialized method for all of the supported values, I can even put an assertion in the unspecialized method.

```
template<vals v>
MyClass<v>::method() {
  assert(check(v) && "Unsupported value!");
}

template<>
MyClass<Val1>::method() {
   // do it!
}
```